# Template for model - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Business model that stores listing information about businesses in specific cities.

These business are to be displayed in various section of the website as a list.

For example, a list of businesses would show up when selecting a specific business category, or a list of businesses will also appear when displaying search results.

I am wondering if there is any way of creating a template for the business list, and then including that template in the category template and the search template.

I am not sure if this is the django way of thinking about this...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create template with list of businesses and include it everywhere:

**inc/business_list.html**

```
<ul>
{% for object in object_list %}
    <li>{{ object }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**search_list.html**

```
...
{% include "inc/business_list.html" with object_list=search_list %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can include templates within other templates

**Snippet**

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

**Template**

```
<html>
{% include "snippet.html" %}
</html>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include